# F# - splitting list into tuple of odd-even lists (by element, not position)

Tags: list, recursion, split, f#, partition

Example: `split [1;3;2;4;7;9];;`
Output: `([1;3;7;9], [2;4])`

I'm new to F# and I can't figure it out.
Can't use the `partition` built in function.

This is what I have so far:

```
let rec split xs = 
    match xs with
    | [] -> [], []
    | xs -> xs, []
    | xh::xt -> let odds, evens = split xt
                if (xh % 2) = 0 then xh::odds, xh::evens
                else xh::odds, evens
```

Fixed code:

```
let rec split xs = 
    match xs with
    | [] -> [], []
    | xh::xt -> let odds, evens = split xt
                if (xh % 2) = 0 then odds, xh::evens
                else xh::odds, evens
```

*Thanks to @TheInnerLight for pointing out my errors: unreachable case and unnecessarily modifying odds

Comment: One word of advice since this appears to be homework: you should tell your professor that you asked for help on Stack Overflow, and exactly what help you got. The best way to do that is to include a link to this question --
 `https://stackoverflow.com/q/44379239/` -- in the comments of your homework when you turn it in. Depending on your professor's policies on asking for help, you may or may not be required to do so, but it's always a good idea to fully disclose any help you got in doing the homework.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question to help others who might find it in the future. However, on Stack Overflow there's no need to put "(Solved)" in a question's title: the fact that you have accepted an answer by giving it a green checkmark is enough to communicate that fact, and in fact people prefer *not* to have "(Solved)" put in question titles. Your willingness to do so is appreciated, though. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built-in `List.partition` function

```
let splitOddEven xs =
    xs |> List.partition (fun x -> x % 2 <> 0)
```

> ```
> splitOddEven [1;3;2;4;7;9];;
> val it : int list * int list = ([1; 3; 7; 9], [2; 4])
> ```

If you want a recursive implementation, I'd probably go for a tail recursive implementation like this:

```
let splitOddEven xs =
    let rec splitOddEvenRec oddAcc evenAcc xs = 
        match xs with
        | [] -> oddAcc, evenAcc
        | xh::xt -> 
            if (xh % 2) = 0 then splitOddEvenRec oddAcc (xh :: evenAcc) xt
            else splitOddEvenRec (xh :: oddAcc) evenAcc xt
    splitOddEvenRec [] [] xs

splitOddEven  [1;3;2;4;7;9]
```

Note that this will give you the two resulting lists in reverse order so you might wish to reverse them yourself.

Comment: That does exactly what I want. However I can't use the List.partition function for this problem. I will look into how that function works and attempt to solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SergioRosales Just added a recursive implementation as well.

Comment: @SergioRosales No problem.  FYI, the implementation you supplied in the question *almost* works.  If you delete the `| xs -> xs, []` pattern match case and replace `if (xh % 2) = 0 then xh::odds, xh::evens` with `if (xh % 2) = 0 then odds, xh::evens`, you have another working implementation.  That implementation isn't tail recursive though because making the recursive call isn't the last thing the function does.  That's why I wanted to show you something different.